# advantage of using static variables in ESP

Tags: c, static, esp32, esp-idf

I'm learning to program an ESP32 in C (ESP IDF). In every example I see a lot of static variables are used. Is this because they compile to smaller binaries or faster execution, or is it because of the non-visibility to other source files?

For example in the phy_init.c file of the espressif source code ([link](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/1cd61607c371f5c8521b27d96bbc3e8080c4f502/components/esp_phy/src/phy_init.c#L46)) from line 46:

```
...
static const char* TAG = "phy_init";
static _lock_t s_phy_access_lock;
static DRAM_ATTR struct {
    int     count;  /* power on count of wifi and bt power domain */
    _lock_t lock;
} s_wifi_bt_pd_controller = { .count = 0 };

/* Indicate PHY is calibrated or not */
static bool s_is_phy_calibrated = false;

/* Reference count of enabling PHY */
static uint8_t s_phy_access_ref = 0;

#if CONFIG_MAC_BB_PD
/* Reference of powering down MAC and BB */
static bool s_mac_bb_pu = true;
#endif

#if CONFIG_IDF_TARGET_ESP32
/* time stamp updated when the PHY/RF is turned on */
static int64_t s_phy_rf_en_ts = 0;
#endif

/* PHY spinlock for libphy.a */
static DRAM_ATTR portMUX_TYPE s_phy_int_mux = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;

/* Memory to store PHY digital registers */
static uint32_t* s_phy_digital_regs_mem = NULL;
```

almost all variables are declared as static. What is the purpose here?

Comment: Because you don’t need them to be non-static, actually. Most boards have single Wi-Fi module physically and keeping it simple kinda promotes static-like design.

Comment: So with simple you mean that the variables are not seen outside? There is no "real" advantage in terms of runtime performance?

Comment: _Is this because they compile to smaller binaries or faster execution_ compared to what?  If you mean is there a difference if you simply remove the keyword `static` then I'd be extremely surprised if there were.  That would be one weird toolchain.

Comment: These variables are accessed by multiple functions in that C file and are, therefore, scoped to be accessible to them in that C file. Additionally, it's intended that access to them be limited to that specific C file (no functions outside of the C file access them directly), so `static is the proper way to specifically scope them to the file they are declared in rather than have them simply be global. The chosen declaration/definition approach has nothing to do with performance.